# Display a form after dropdown selection to edit mysql data from a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

i have the following code:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="deleteuser">Delete User</option>
    <option value="assignuser">Assign User</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form id="deleteuser"></form>
<form id="assignuser"></form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var i = x.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.options[i].text;
}
</script>
```

After the user selects one of the dropdown options, i want a separate form to appear for each selection where the user will edit data from rows. Sorry if i did not describe it correct. 
With the current code after the selection it displays the Text selected.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to make a form appear instead of displaying the text selected? Should i delete the line document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.options[i].text; and place my form inside the demo <p> ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<form></form>"`?

Comment: I don't think that's what i asked, i want to display a different form depending on the user selection from the dropdown.

Comment: @grh0ul Different form means what actually you want? <form></form> <form></form> <form></form> like this

Comment: Say for example the user Selects Apple, i want a form where its content will change depending on the dropdown selection

Comment: @grh0ul can you please share your form and what content you want to change on selection so we'll get clear picture

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a dynamic form system; you can either make your javascript reload the page with a query string attached to it like

> localhost/index.php?getform=apple

and have a switch case at the bottom of the page to show one of the forms depending on the **getform** value

> Something like

```html
<form>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="deleteuser">Delete User</option>
    <option value="assignuser">Assign User</option>
  </select>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_GET["getform"]) && !empty($_GET["getfrom"])){
    switch ($_GET["getfrom"]){
       case "deleteduser":
?>
       <form>
        The form here
       </form>
<?php
       break;
       case "assignuser":
?>
       <form>
       The form here
       </form>
<?php
       break;
    }
}
?>
```

This will then show the from depending on the value passed to it

Or if you want to populate a from dynamically; you can use something like Ajax to retrieve a from from an other page depending on the argument it receive.

```html
<script>
function loadDoc(arg) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getform.php?fromType="+arg, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

This will change the form depending on what user select without having to refresh the page at all.

> arg is the argument to send to the form

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This site might be a useful site for you https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp